# Why is an 'ActionListener' not a 'ClickListener'

Tags: java

Why is an `ActionListener` not a `ClickListener`?

Comment: @JHarley - Welcome to PSE.  Please read the FAQ where you'll find 6 guidelines to asking questions (for all SE sites).  This question probably is best suited for SO as you are asking about API specifics which are generally off-topic here.

Comment: FYI: [Why do so many people write JAVA instead of Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2271/241)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are not always clicking, pressing enter also can be handled by an ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

it think it's just the same but personally i prefer action or actionlistener it much easier to learn and the code is reusable. but still it depends on what you really want to do.